# How to replicate code block with `<pre>` tag

Tags: html, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

If we have this block:

````
```java
  System.out.println("foo");
```
````

how can replicate the above with `<pre>` tags?

```
<pre lang="java">
  System.out.println("foo");
</pre>
```

is there a class or attribute we can add to the pre tag to tell github markdown to know which language is in there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this

```
<pre>
   <code class="language-java">
      System.out.println("foo");
   </code>
</pre>
```

Found it on [GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://github.github.com/gfm/#fenced-code-blocks)

Comment: This is also the recommended way to mark up a code block in the [HTML5 spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-code-element).